# Mouse disappears when idle?

Tags: mouse

I just upgraded a computer that I don't use frequently from Lubuntu 15.04 to Lubuntu 18.04 LTS.

Now whenever the mouse is idle for a second it disappears. This is especially annoying because while it's hidden Chrome does not respond to the mouse wheel. It reappears immediately when I move the mouse and works, so it's not a major problem but still quite annoying. I can't find any mouse settings that might be controlling this behavior or any help from a google search.

Comment: Do you have `unclutter` installed or running?  Run `ps -ef | grep unclutter`   Unclutter is an app that hides the mouse within so many seconds of your choosing.

Comment: You're very welcome!  Glad it worked for you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Terrance pointed out, this was caused by unclutter.

I simply killed the process and used `apt-get remove unclutter` to uninstall it.

Comment: @VolkerSiegel This is indeed an answer. They *are* the author ;)

Comment: @Zanna I simply killed the process and used apt-get remove to uninstall it.